# How to get the selected value in Select element in my case?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to get the option value when user selects a option in Angular way. I have something like'

```
<div ng-controller="test">
  <select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="product.name for product in products">
     <option value="">Please select a product</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

In my js

```
app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {

    console($scope.selectedProduct)   -> undefined. 

})
```

I want to get the selected value when user makes a selection. Can anyone help me about it? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngChange` to fire an event whenever the value changes in the view:

```
<select ng-model="selectedProduct" ng-options="product.name for product in products"
        ng-change="doSomething(selectedProduct)">
    <option value="">Please select a product</option>
</select>

app.controller('test', function ($scope, $http, $modal) {
    ...
    $scope.doSomething = function (product) {
        // Do stuff with product
    };
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/K8H43/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="selectProduct" ng-options="option.id as option.name for option in options" ></select>
```

Secondly, where is your `products` in your controller?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZArF4DrayIIsrV1mLLeB) is an example of this working. You should define a default value within your controller's `$scope` to ensure the value is defined. From there it is easy to access the model via `{{ myproduct }}` or `$scope.myproduct` depending on where it is being accessed.